# Custom apache error logs for the directories inside the document root

Tags: 14.04, apache2, log, error-handling

I stuck with this issue, googled it around and got some solutions but unlikely it is not working properly. Can anyone give a solution for this please,

I'm running Apache2 in Ubuntu 14.04 machine. Have only one virtual host running in it
and have a document root under `/var/www/html` where our resides.

Inside html directory our code contains sub-directories. For eg. dir1, dir2. 
I need the error log should be customized like all the error log related to code under dir1 should resides inside dir1 and same for dir2.

How I can customize the error logs?

Comment: Why not separate them in 2 different virtual hosts?

Comment: No. Customer don't want us to do that Dan!

Answer (score 1):

According this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395043/apache-server-multiple-directories-different-error-logs

It is not doable for the error log as ErrorLog directive works only in server config or virtual host context.
It is possible to separate AccessLog with features provided by setenvif module.

Alternatively one can try something like that:

`ErrorLog "|/usr/bin/tee -a  ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log /var/www/apachelogs/error.txt"`

Just put more sophisticated filtering script in between and may be you manage to achieve what you need.

Some nitpicking, why would you need error log in the directory with code ? Imho it is a security threat.

Comment: Thanks mestia. The solution which you have suggested, I guess it will not separate the logs based on directories. We need this because each developers are working on different directory (code ). They want to know whats the error they are getting particularly for the code which they are working on.

Comment: In this case I guess you can set a variable with setenvif and place this variable to the error log file by adjusting the error log directive and adding logging of %{VARNAME}e. is this works just filter the corresponding values before giving them to the developers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/app/subapp1(/|$) subapp1
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/app/subapp2(/|$) subapp2

CustomLog /absolute/path/to/app/subapp1/log/access_log common env=subapp1
CustomLog /absolute/path/to/app/subapp2/log/access_log common env=subapp2
```

Source:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460757/generate-access-logs-for-different-subdirectories-in-apache

Comment: Thanks for the reply George. I already tried this solution, it is working for access_logs but not for error.logs.

Comment: Even when you edit the name to ErrorLog?

Comment: Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395043/apache-server-multiple-directories-different-error-logs

Comment: CustomLog /var/www/html/app1/error.log  env=app1
ErrorLog /var/www/html/app1/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/html/app2/error.log  env=app2
ErrorLog /var/www/html/app2/error.log

This is how I edited for error.log. Is it correct?

Comment: I tried even that, I got this error    AH00526: Syntax error on line 50 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:
ErrorLog takes one argument, The filename of the error log

Comment: Yes it does indeed I was wondering if separate lives can work. Now remove one line and try and see if it does work at all!

Comment: Which line should I remove and give a try? Is the which is pointing to env variable or the other one?

Comment: remove this: `CustomLog /absolute/path/to/app/subapp2/log/access_log common env=subapp2` and see if it logs for the other dir

Comment: No luck George! not working. It is continuously generating "env=app2" this message.

Comment: Please remove that `SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/app/subapp2(/|$) subapp2` too, it should hopefully

Comment: Still getting same message env=app2.

Comment: Did you restart apache?

Comment: Yes, I did after each changes I made

Answer (score 0):

Simply use in your vhost

> **ErrorLog error.log**

and it will write error file in the same folder in which the script causing the error resides.

An error in

> http://example.com/some/dir/test.php

will write the error in

> /public_html/some/dir/error.log